# Quickblox sample chat unauthorized

Tags: ios, xcode, quickblox

I am trying to create a basic chat application in xcode using Quickblox.
I downloaded a chat project example that Quickblox supplies [from here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/archive/master.zip) and entered my details in the AppDelegate class.
However when I run the application I get the error message: unauthorized.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Chat application uses predefined demo user login & password.

If you put your app details - you also have to update your user demo user login & password. Go to admin panel and create a new user for example.